# Custom font size on universal storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, font-size

I was following this tutorial: [Font size on universal storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25085923/font-size-on-universal-storyboard) to have an adapted font with iPad or iPhone, it's working with the System font but not with a custom font. That's it' normal or I haven't imported corrected my custom font ?

Bundle sources: 
[image]

Choosing font: 
[image]

dropdown list:

[image]

Comment: Are you able to choose the custom font from the dropdown in the storyboard?

Comment: So apparently you are able to choose it which means it is not the custom font's issue, Try any other font given.

Comment: @LinusG. Sure look my edit I put a screenshot, the text is displayed corruptly but when i switch on iPad the size still the same

Answer (score 0):

Following is the common mistake happen when using custom font just go thru all the steps.

Step 1: Include your fonts in your XCode project

Step 2: Make sure that they’re included in the target

Step 3: Double check that your fonts are included as Resources in your bundle

Step 4: Include your iOS custom fonts in your application plist
[image]

Step 5: Find the name of the font

In Swift

```
func displayAllFont(){

    for family: String in UIFont.familyNames()
    {
        print("Family name:  \(family)")
        for names: String in UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(family)
        {
            print("    Font name: \(names)")
        }
    }
}
```

In Objective-C

```
NSArray *familyNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[UIFont familyNames]];
NSArray *fontNames;
NSInteger indFamily, indFont;
for (indFamily=0; indFamily<[familyNames count]; ++indFamily)
{
    NSLog(@"Family name: %@", [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]);
    fontNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:
                 [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:
                  [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]]];
    for (indFont=0; indFont<[fontNames count]; ++indFont)
    {
        NSLog(@"    Font name: %@", [fontNames objectAtIndex:indFont]);
    }

}
```

Comment: This does not seem to be relevant at all since he is able to choose his custom font from the dropdown in the storyboard.

Comment: Once all those point follow it's must see into dropdown in storyboard.

Comment: @NimitParekh , Step 5 is not a question here.

Comment: @ZaidPathan If you follow this step correctly that fonts available into storyboard.For step 5 for if you can able to see the exact name of the font using this code.

Comment: Where I have to put the function ?

Comment: Any where you can use this code but highly suggest to insert code into `appdelegate` so easy to find.

Comment: He already finds it! That is not the issue! Jeez... @NimitParekh

Comment: @LinusG. Sure still doesn't work I don't understand why, are you sure it's possible to do it with a custom font ?

Comment: you do not need to include custom fonts in the plist anymore when working with the IB

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and solved it by reverting the [label's font attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwGJZ.png) to the System's instead of the Custom font

Then programmatically changed the font to the desired custom one
like this

```
[[UILabel appearance] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Frutiger" size:75.0]];
```

Comment: Hello. This question is tagged "swift": please edit your answer with Swift code. Thanks!