# Different fonts in iphones model not ipad

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, fonts

I want to change font size as per iPhone models Globaly in my App. I am not asking about iphone and ipads. Adaptivity and Layout can difference between ipad and iphone not in different iphone models.

1. I am facing problem with font in different font sizes in different iPhone Models. I am working with auto-layout and I want to change font size of Label, UITextField etc. as per iPhone 4, iPhone 5/5c/5s and iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+.
2. I don't want to change font with if...else if...else conditions for every object. it should be change the font size with single implementation and effect in whole App.

Any suggestion and advice acceptable. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If you use predefined styles like 'title' 'header' and etc it would change per device.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25085923/font-size-on-universal-storyboard