# IOS anywidth / anyheight font size not increase in ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, autolayout, font-size, size-classes

I am trying to increase Font size when Device change to iPad from iPhone. but there is no effect when i run into iPad. I am Using .XIB.

Here is my Setting.

**1)** I have Enable Size Classes.

[image]

**2)** I have set wAny/hAny in Storyboard.

[image]

**3)** I have set wR/hR in Font storyboard.

[image]

Constrain for **Continue Label**.

[image]

but when i run it into iPad there is no effect in Fontsize in iPad.

Please guide me where i am doing mistake.

**Application is based on Landscape Mode**

Edit :-

[image]

Comment: This is a size class bug. Custom fonts do not work with size classes.

Comment: i have tried to get solution but looks like there is issue in size class with custom `fonts`. With `System fonts` its working fine. For solution you can change `Font` with `Manual Coding`.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting font size for `w R and h R` that means when you textfield opens in ipad then it consider this font size because it is override ipad portrait mode. So, if you remove this then it will take `w any h any`.

`w any h any` only called when you are not override it. for example you are making universal app and you set constraint for `w any h any` and `w compact h regular` (for all iphone in portrait) then when your app open in iphone portrait it takes setups of `w compact h regular` and run in ipad then it takes setup of `w any h any` because you haven't explicitly override size class for ipad portrait. likewise if you are only giving constraints for `w any h any` then both take this size class. so in short first it is find that is there any overridden size class for specific mode. if it is not then by default it use `any any` size class.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Thanks for the replay friend then what is the solution how can i set in landscape mode ?

Comment: RR means ? regular height regular width ? one more thing i have notice that it will not work with custom font ?

Comment: yes, regular height regular width. I don't ever try with custom font so i don't have much idea about that

Comment: I have already set Regular height / Regular height please check in above image .

Comment: then it should work if ipad in both orientation. your font size should be 55.0 in both orientation in ipad. why are you setting font for wAny hC ?

Comment: i have set just it for testing purpose . because it dosent work in RR.

Comment: remove than and just keep RR only. and make sure that you have given proper constraints for RR and installed it.

Comment: i have tested it with removing .  can you please check this once i think problem with custom font. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26166737/custom-font-sizing-in-xcode6-size-classes-not-working-properly-w-custom-fonts

Comment: I have check in my demo by changing font to custom. i have kept `Cochin` font for both RR and AA with diiferent size like 10 and 30. it works fine. in ipad it's displays 30 and in iphone its displays 10 font size

Comment: don't know i have tried a lot to changing font but can't.

Comment: I think there is another mistake in constrains or else. try to change font family to `Helvetica` and then check what happen

Comment: yes if i change it to helvetika then it works fine .

Comment: from where you are getting this `CarterOne` font?

Comment: from our designer. i have set it in .plist.

Comment: I think if you put custom fonts outside from library then it should not work with font size. are you able to increase this font's size without using size class? have you check that? take two label sent this custom font and give different size. don't override any size class only just keep any any and check font size is changeable?

Answer (score 0):

When you're using universal storyboards,
each text-displaying control in a storyboard will now have a small + icon to the left of the font setting in the Attributes Inspector. If you click it, 
It will allow you to set different values for different size classes.

I hope, it will help you.

Comment: thanks for the replay but i have already done this all setting but i am not able to get desire output in ipad.

Comment: What do u want in ipad exactly?

Comment: I need textsize change according to device. if device is iphone then, textsize will  20 and if ipad then textsize will be 55.

Comment: Frist find size of screen:
CGRect screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;
Then set the font size as a percentage of the screen size:

CGFloat fontScreenPercentage = 0.05f;
UIFont *myFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:(fontScreenPercentage * screenWidth)]

Comment: I need to change it from storyboard.

Comment: Review this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25085923/font-size-on-universal-storyboard